# Google OR-Tools VRP Using both distance and time constraints

Tags: optimization, routes, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am trying to solve a Vehicle Routing Problem using Google's OR-Tools. I completed basic tasks but I want to prepare a more complex model which has both time constraints and capacity constraints. vehicles need to deliver quantities in specific time slots. how can I combine these two options in one task?

Cant add specific code bc it's the same with the initial code by google just need to know if ı can do it or not and if I can what would be the ideal notion here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the cvrptw example is doing.
See https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrptw.py